# How to implement the find() function from scratch (No libraries)

Tags: python

The problem wants us to write a function that basically does what the find() function does but handles a wildcard as well. As it being a lab/homework, no libraries are allowed (such as re) as it is graded through Mimir.

The approach that I was taking (a TA recommended as well) was to get the function working properly without the wildcard. This is what I've tried so far:

```
def findMatch(self, text, start=0):
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        if text[i] == self._pattern[0]:
            j = 0
        while j < len(self._pattern):
            if text[i + j] == self._pattern[j]:
                j += 1
            else:
                break
```

The error I get is: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: well, what happens if your `if` statement is not satisfied? `j` never ends up getting set

Answer (score 0):

The error is a pretty good indicator. If the text doesn't match the first letter, then you do not define `j`, but use it in the next line. I suspect you dropped a level of indentation:

```py
def findMatch(self, text, start=0):
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        if text[i] == self._pattern[0]:
            j = 0
            while j < len(self._pattern):   # Notice this line is indented
                if text[i + j] == self._pattern[j]:
                    j += 1
                else:
                    break
```

I should also note that you don't currently *do anything* if the full word matches. You will probably want to return the location `i` (or something along that idea) if the entire pattern is matched.